# How to reverse elements in char array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to reverse the contents of a char array. But I seem to be getting a garbage value for the first element in my output. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
int main() {
    int size = 0;
    char arr[100];

    cout << "Enter how many elements are added to array" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter " << size << " elements " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Input: [ " ;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

    cout << "Output: [";
    for(int j = size; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `for(int j = size; j >= 0; j--)` is looping over `size+1` elements.  The first value output (`arr[size]`) is garbage due to undefined behavior, because you never initialized it to anything.

Comment: the first element you print is `arr[size]` which is after the end of the used elements

Comment: ohh I got it. My bad , a newbie mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why was the question closed? There's no "typo" here. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Actually, this is the sort of mistakes that a debugger was made for. When looking at the array, you would have spotted that the weird value was right after your last entry on index 'size'.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to indicate that it is solved. Instead accept an answer. Make one yourself if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are printing an element that was never initialized:

```
for(int j = size; j >= 0; j--)
{
    cout << arr[j] << " ";
}
```

If you entered 10 values for example, the indices of those values are 0 to 9. But you are accessing element 10, which was never initialized and thus you get undefined behavior. You need this instead:

```
for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
    cout << arr[j] << " ";
}
```